# shiny dashboard: jump to specific element in app by clicking infoBox

Tags: html, r, shiny, href, shinydashboard

In my shiny app I want to add an option to let users jump to a specific element in the app (a table, a plot, just anything with an id), on current or different `tab`, by clicking on `infoBox` (or any other object I want).

My solution was to surround `infoBox` with `div` and add the`href=#id_of_element` attribute. Unfortunately this solution works only for `tabs` with an extra `"data-toggle" = "tab"` attribute (it also does not change the opened `tab` to `active`), but that's not what I want.

My question is: how can I add the mentioned option and why this solution isn't working? Here is a small example what I want to do:

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "blue",
     dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
              menuItem("Tab1", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                       menuSubItem("SubTab1", tabName = "sub1", icon = icon("bar-chart")),
                          menuSubItem("SubTab2", tabName = "sub2", icon = icon("database"))),
              menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("users"))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
       tabItem(tabName = "sub1",
          tags$div(href="#s2t2",
                   infoBox(value = "Go to table 2 in SubTab2 (not working)",title = "Click me")),
          tags$div(href="#shiny-tab-tab2", "data-toggle" = "tab",
                   infoBox(value = "Go to Tab2 (this works)",title = "Click me"))
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "sub2",
               tableOutput("s2t1"),
               tableOutput("s2t2")
                ),
        tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
                tableOutput("t2t1"),
                tableOutput("t2t2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

SERVER:

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  output$s2t1<- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$s2t2<- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$t2t1<- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$t2t2<- renderTable(mtcars)
} )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").click(function() {
       $(".sidebar-menu a[href=\'#shiny-tab-tab2\']").tab("show");
setTimeout(function(){
        var top = $("#t2t2").position().top;
        $(window).scrollTop( top );
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

where `div1` is `div` around `infoBox`